# DBA role is not applied

Tags: oracle, permissions

This worked yesterday, but now it won't.
We've defined a user 'DEPLOY' on 'Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0' which will be used for deployments into each environment - DEV, TEST and PROD.

Yesterday DEPLOY was given the following in DEV and TEST environments and all worked OK:

```
    grant DBA to DEPLOY;
    ALTER USER DEPLOY DEFAULT ROLE DBA;
    
    select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where USERNAME = 'DEPLOY';
```

Today somehow the DBA roles have been revoked.
And even if I try to recreate the DEPLOY user in DEV it does not show the DBA role being granted.

```
    DROP   USER DEPLOY CASCADE;
    create user DEPLOY identified by "*********" default tablespace USERS quota unlimited on USERS;
    
    grant create session to DEPLOY;
    grant DBA to DEPLOY WITH ADMIN OPTION;
    ALTER USER DEPLOY DEFAULT ROLE DBA;
    
    select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS where GRANTED_ROLE = 'DBA';
```

The last query line above returns only the SYS user, which I'm currently using to do this.
I also tried the create procedure above with a new different user 'TEST1211',
same result, DBA role not showing.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I'm unable to grant DBA?

Comment: Did you check `DBA_ROLE_PROVS`??

Comment: Thanks Michael, I see it now.
I thought being logged on as SYS and selecting from USER_ROLE_PRIVS would show me everything.